# Unique property fails in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, waterline

The following code represents an Account Model in Sails.js v0.9.4 .

```
 module.exports = {

      attributes: {
        email: {
          type: 'email',
          unique: true,
          required: true
        },
        password:{
          type: 'string',
          minLength: 6,
          maxLength: 15,
          required:true
        }
      }

    };
```

When I send two POSTS and a PUT request via [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to localhost:8080/account, the unique property of the email fails.
Specifically, I send the following HTTP requests from Postman:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/account?email=foo@gmail.com&password=123456  
POST http://localhost:8080/account?email=bar@gmail.com&password=123456    
PUT  http://localhost:8080/account?id=1&email=bar@gmail.com  
GET  http://localhost:8080/account
```

The last GET request shows me:

```
[
  {
    "email": "bar@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "createdAt": "2013-09-30T18:33:00.415Z",
    "updatedAt": "2013-09-30T18:34:35.349Z",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "email": "bar@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "createdAt": "2013-09-30T18:33:44.402Z",
    "updatedAt": "2013-09-30T18:33:44.402Z",
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

Should this happen?
*For those who don't know, [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) generates by default an id which automatically increments in every insertion.

Comment: I could overcome this "faulty" behavior by setting `autoPK:false`.

Comment: When I put my autoPK to false, my id column got deleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because your schema is not updated in your disk database (".tmp/disk.db").

You need to shutdown sails, drop your DB and restart sails.
The DB will be reconstruct with your good schema.

Attention : the data will be drop too !

If you want keep your data, you can just update the schema part of ".tmp/disk.db".

What I have doing to keep data and rebuild schema by sails.js :

1. copy ".tmp/disk.db"
2. clean ".tmp/disk.db"
3. shutdown sails.js
4. start sails.js
   -> the database is empty and the schema is updated
5. copy old "counters" part
6. copy old "data" part

You must have this in your schema (file ".tmp/disk.db" -> "schema" part) for the unique field :

```
  "xxx": {
    "type": "string",
    "unique": true
  },
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: A better solution is to tell Waterline to update the db schema. 
See the `migrate` setting, and make sure it is set to `alter` (`models.migrate = 'alter'`)

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same issue. To solve it, you have to avoid using the 'disk' ORM adapter. For some reason it appears that it doesn't support uniqueness checks.

Other adapters such as mongo and mysql should support uniqueness checks, so this shouldn't be an issue outside of development.

For the course of development, change the default adapter in `config/adapters.js` from 'disk' to 'memory'. Should look like this:

```
module.exports.adapters = {

  // If you leave the adapter config unspecified 
  // in a model definition, 'default' will be used.
  'default': 'memory',

  // In-memory adapter for DEVELOPMENT ONLY
  memory: {
    module: 'sails-memory'
  },

  ...
};
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried the 'disk' and 'memory' adapters before posting my problem on stackoverflow. Didn't try a database though.

Comment: Did you try it in combination with autoPK: true?

Comment: Yes I did.If you notice my POST requests don't require an id (that means it's enabled, i.e. `autoPK:true`).

Comment: What does config/adapters.js look like for you?

Comment: The default (the one that comes when it is created with the `sails` command)  config/adapters.js with `'default': 'memory'`

Comment: Seems it's not fixed for localdisks on sails 0.10.x
For sails-memory, it works good for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain this is the issue, but have you added `schema:true` to your models and adapters?

My mongo adapter config looks like this:

```
    module.exports.adapters = {
            'default': 'mongo',
            mongo: {
                    module: 'sails-mongo',
                    url: process.env.DB_URL,
                    schema: true
            }
    };
```

And my User model looks like this (trimmed a bit):

```
    module.exports = {
            schema: true,
            attributes: {
                    username: {
                            type: 'string',
                            required: true,
                            unique: true
                    }
                    //...
            }
    };
```

Comment: I don't think that the `schema` property matters when the `default` property is either `disk` or `memory`. My conclusion is based on the [Sails model documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models). Out of curiosity I gave the `default:memory` and `default:disk` with `schema:true` a go.
It didn't work. :(
In the meantime I'll just switch to MongoDB and continue my work from there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to delete current database to solve this, in stead change the waterline `migrate` option from `safe` to `alter`. This way the underlying database will adapt this setting.

I wouldn't recommend `migrate: alter` in a production environment, though. ;)

---

Here is my `/config/local.js`:

```
module.exports = {

    ... 

    models: {
        migrate: 'alter'
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation of sails

You should configure the option "migrate" in "alter" to create the schemas with their indexes

> There's nothing wrong with adding or removing validations from your
>   models as your app evolves. But once you go to production, there is
>   one very important exception: unique. During development, when your
>   app is configured to use migrate: 'alter', you can add or remove
>   unique validations at will. However, if you are using migrate: safe
>   (e.g. with your production database), you will want to update
>   constraints/indices in your database, as well as migrate your data by
>   hand.

http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations

Answer (score 0):

```
var InvoiceSchema = new Schema({
 email: {type: 'email', required: true}
  name : {type: String}
});
InvoiceScheme({email: 1}, {unique: true});
```

Set Uniquee In Nodejs