# Unique doesn't work on Node.js Sails.js "sails-mysql"

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sails.js

I've just started to get into the framework of Sails for Node. But it seems like I can't get the unique- requirements to work when adding for example users to the sails-mysql database. I can atm add unlimited number of new users with the same username and email.

From what I have read it should work, I did also try with sails-memory and there this exact code did work. Is it something I have missed out?

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {

username: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  unique: true
},

firstname: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},

lastname: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},

password: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},

birthdate: {
  type: 'date',
  required: true
},

email: {
  type: 'email',
  required: true,
  unique: true
},

phonenumber: 'string',

// Create users full name automaticly
fullname: function(){
  return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
}

}


};
```

As I mentioned above, this does work with the memory-storage. And now I have also tried with mongodb where it does work fins as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101531/unique-property-fails-in-sails-js

Comment: He said he solved it by autoPK:false, but that does just delete my id column. And he accepted sails-memory as answer but that will just not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got support from Sails.js on twitter: "it uses the db layer- suspect it's an issue with automigrations. Would you try in a new MySQL db?"

This answer did work, a new db and everything was just working :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, since sails uses auto-migrations, if you initially start the server and your model does not have an attribute as unique, the table is built without the unique (index) switch. If you then change an existing attribute in the model to `unique`, the table will not be rebuilt the subsequent times you start the server.

One remedy during development is to set migrations in your model to `drop` like this:

```
module.exports = {

  migrate: 'drop' // drops all your tables and then re-create them Note: You loose underlying.

  attributes: {
     ...
  }
};
```

That way, the db would be rebuilt each time you start the server. This would of course drop any existing data as well.